# Past perfect tenses in compound and complex sentences

Tags: tense, past-tense, sequence-of-tenses

Consider the following sequence of events.

My smartphone starts behaving weirdly. **On a Friday**, I send an email describing the problem to the customer care of the manufacturer of my smartphone. The employee of the manufacturer who reads my email explains my problem to a customer support officer and asks him to call me to tell me how to fix the problem. But for some reason the customer support officer doesn't understand the problem correctly. He calls me, quickly gives me a wrong advice and hangs up. After that, I apply his advice and learns that it doesn't work. I email the customer care again **on the following Monday**. The same customer support officer calls me up again, but this time he abuses me instead of giving advice and quickly hangs up. Now I have to email the customer care for the third time. So, I write again, and this is where I have some problems with past perfect tenses in compound/complex sentences.

Which one of the following is correct:

1. Dear customer care, after I emailed you again on Monday, the customer support officer **who called after I had emailed you** for the first time on last Friday, called again.
2. Dear customer care, after I emailed you again on Monday, the customer support officer **who had called after I emailed you** for the first time on last Friday, called again.
3. Dear customer care, after I emailed you again on Monday, the customer support officer **who had called after I had emailed you** for the first time on last Friday, called again.

Comment: Even though it's "syntactically valid", using two consecutive Perfect forms separated by ***after*** would normally be seen as "clumsy", to say the least. But you don't *need* to use Past Perfect anywhere here (both *logic*, and the fact of including the word ***after***, make it clear when happened before what). So as ever, my advice is not to use the Perfect form at all.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica please help me out. There may be better ways than to use past perfect here but past perfect tenses is always what I have problems with. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You've given us 3 versions to choose from - 1:SimplePast+Perfect, 2:Perfect+SimplePast, and 3:Perfect+Perfect. Imho, *by far* the best choice is just SimplePast+SimplePast, but if you insist on using a Perfect verb form, it would be better to go for #1 or #2 there (I can't see any reason to favour one of those over the other). But to repeat myself in different words, most of the time the "best" way for you to use Perfect forms is *not to use them*.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you, sir. Are none of them incorrect? How is "who called after I had emailed you" not different from "who had called after I emailed you"?

Comment: They're "not different" because both of them (probably pointlessly) include an instance of the Past Perfect that can't possibly affect the meaning (it's logically impossible to assign any different meanings to the words, regardless of what your understanding of "grammar" might suggest). That's all there is to it.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica ok, sir. Thank you. Sorry English is difficult for me.

Comment: That's why we're here! To try and make English *less* difficult for you! The best way for you to learn about (Past *and* Present) Perfect verb forms is to think in terms of *avoiding them as much as possible*. That way you'll only have to learn those contexts where you ***must*** use the Perfect, which will be *much* easier than the approach some people take. They try to learn about all the contexts where they ***can*** use Perfect forms, but that's not really worth it. Always prefer simpler verb forms unless your context is one where you're forced to use complex tenses.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you sir.